# How does the Circle Pad Pro affect Resident Evil: Revelations' controls?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, resident-evil-revelations

I've played through the first level of *Resident Evil: Revelations* without the Circle Pad Pro. Having played through almost all *Resident Evil* games, I'm familiar with the "tank controls" of the series. However, the controls for this game seem especially clunky and sluggish.

In what way does the Circle Pad Pro affect the controls? Is it possible to do things with the CPP that aren't possible without?

Answer (score 1):

It's basically the same, just personal preference really.